# Get selected database name - SSMS Extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsix

I have created a SSMS extension. I would like to trigger an event whenever developer clicks on database in object explorer.

[image: Databases]

Suppose, if a user selects AdventureWorks2016, I would like to capture that event and do some action in my extension.

TIA

Comment: I have some code here that could get you started: https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/blob/master/src/GUI/SSMSToolbox/SSMSEngine/ObjectExplorerManager.cs

Comment: Great :) It worked @ErikEJ Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have some code here that could get you started:

https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/blob/master/src/GUI/SSMSToolbox/SSMSEngine/ObjectExplorerManager.cs